# Modify the self-made concat function so it will accept more than two arguments

Tags: c++, c, char

I have programmed a self-made concat function:

```
char * concat (char * str1, char * str2) {
    for (int i=0; i<BUFSIZ; i++) {
        if (str1[i]=='\0') {
            for (int j=i; j<BUFSIZ; j++) {
                if (str2[j-i]=='\0') return str1;
                else str1[j]=str2[j-i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I want to concat more than 2 strings, i.e. buf temp1 temp2,
I have to use something like that:

```
strcpy(buf, concat(concat(buf,temp1),temp2));
```

Please tell me, is there a simple way to modify my function so it would accept many arguments?

Comment: C or C++? This is highly relevant.

Comment: Not simple, but you could use var_args type input.  Shutter.

Comment: If you know a way that works for C++ but doesn't for C, it is still interesting...

Comment: @JakeBadlands: The vast majority of the techniques that you'd use in a real C++ program won't work in C. The two are _different_ languages; please state which one you're using.

Comment: Lol - It's still morning here and I haven't had my coffee :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is `varargs`.  This allows you to write a C function which accepts a variable number of arguments.  It's how functions like `printf` are implemented

```
char* concat(size_t argCount, ...) {
  va_list ap;

  char* pFinal = ... // Allocate the buffer
  while (argCount) {
    char* pValue = va_arg(ap, char*);
    argCount--;

    // Concat pValue to pFinal

  }
  va_end(ap);

  return pFinal;
}
```

Now you can call concat with a variable number of arguments

```
concat(2, "hello", " world");
concat(4, "hel", "lo", " wo", "rld");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. When I try something like that: `char buf[BUFSIZ]; strcpy(buf, concat(2, "hello", " world"));` I get an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS during runtime. Error line is `char* pValue = va_arg(ap, char*);`

Comment: @JakeBadlands you can only modify writable memory, which string literals aren't. You have to: `char h[6] = "hel"; concat(2, h, "lo");`

Comment: I have changed the line with "allocate the buffer" to `char* pFinal = (char *) malloc (BUFSIZ);`. Now, when I try char `h[BUFSIZ]="hel"; concat(2, h, "lo");`, h contains "hel" while it should contain "hello"

Answer (score 4):

In C++ use string instead of `char*` and functions: `std::string result = std::string(buf) + temp1 + temp2;`

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> // for the demo only

std::string concat(std::string const& a) {
  return a;
}

template <typename... Items>
std::string concat(std::string const& a, std::string const& b, Items&&... args) {
  return concat(a + b, args...);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << concat("0", "1", "2", "3") << "\n";
}
```

See it in action at [ideone](http://ideone.com/5sSuH):

```
0123
```

Of course, you can add some overloads for efficiency.